# How can these two similar methods be DRYed up?

Tags: ruby

I have these two methods that obviously have many similarities. However, their difference is fundamental enough that I haven't yet figured out a way to get them to share some code.

Any ideas from Ruby gurus are greatly appreciated!

Method 1:

```
def fill_out(page, *fields)    
    methods=[ lambda{|p, f| p.send(f).fit(instance_variable_get f) },
              lambda{|p, f| p.send(f).pick!(instance_variable_get f) } ]
    fields.shuffle.each do |field|
      x = page.send(field).class.to_s=='Watir::Select' ? 1 : 0
      methods[x].call(page, field)
    end
end
```

Method 2:

```
def fill_out_item(name, page, *fields)  
  methods=[ lambda{|n, p, f| p.send(f, n).fit(instance_variable_get f) },
            lambda{|n, p, f| p.send(f, n).pick!(instance_variable_get f) } ]
  fields.shuffle.each do |field|
    x = page.send(field, name).class.to_s=='Watir::Select' ? 1 : 0
    methods[x].call(name, page, field)
  end
end
```

Comment: Why do you want to DRY them up? Do you expect them to change often? Overly "clever" DRY code is much worse than a little repetition. And these ones are almost too "clever" already.

Comment: Well, I suppose the argument for maintaining readability is a good one.

And I don't expect them to change at all, so... Perhaps best to leave them be as is.

Comment: Naming your array methods gives a clash in names (the usual methods array). Though your code clearly doesn't depend on using the original methods array, I do think it is still good practice to avoid that name clash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you just need `f,n` to map to `f` if `n` is nil. Can be done via `*[f,n].compact` or `n ? f : *[f,n]`

```
def fill_out_item(name, page, *fields)  
  methods=[ lambda{|n, p, f| p.send(*[f, n].compact).fit(instance_variable_get f) },
            lambda{|n, p, f| p.send(*[f, n].compact).pick!(instance_variable_get f) } ]
  fields.shuffle.each do |field|
    x = page.send(*[field, name].compact).class.to_s=='Watir::Select' ? 1 : 0
    methods[x].call(name, page, field)
  end
end

def fill_out(page, *fields)    
    fill_out_item(nil, page, *fields)
end
```

Not sure why you need `lambdas` here unless this is simplified version of the code. You can also do :

```
def fill_out_item(name, page, *fields)  
  fields.shuffle.each do |field|
    obj = page.send(*[field, name].compact)
    var = instance_variable_get field
    obj.class.to_s == 'Watir::Select' ?  obj.pick!(var) :  obj.fit(var)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! The lambdas are a legacy of when I wasn't sure exactly how many different methods would be used here when I first tackled this problem. Now with the refactoring it's clear there's only two needed, so you're right to get rid of them. Woohoo! Thanks for the help!